# @ and Sequence ( and /@ )

Tags: function-construction, map, sequence

```
list = { {a,b}, {c,d}, {e,g} }
```

How to efficiently get

> > { f[a,b], f[c,d], f[e,g] }

I tried various combinations using `@`, `/@` together with `Sequence`, like

```
f[Sequence[#]] /@ list
```

but no success.

Comment: `f@@@list`.....

Comment: Yeah, `Apply` to the 1st level.

Answer (score 7):

*Turning a comment into an answer.*

```
f@@@list
```

The long form of this is

```
Apply[f,list,{1}]
```

and it can be generalized to depth `d` by

```
Apply[f,list,{d}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, g}};

Apply[f, list, {1}]
```

Or short hand of this

```
f@@@list
```

Both gives

> { f[a,b], f[c,d], f[e,g] }

Answer (score 3):

```
f[Sequence @@ #] & /@ list
```

Finally worked. But is this the best(most efficient) way?

Comment: As Henrik commented, this is the best(most efficient) way `f@@@list`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
Map[f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, list]
{f[a, b], f[c, d], f[e, g]}
```

Or more compactly:

```
f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ list
```