# Mapping over array/matrix the efficient(compact) way

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation, pure-function

**Update**

In short, I have `myCAans[[1 ;; 5]]` like this:

> > {{0, 0, 0, True, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, 0, "T0", 39}, {0, 0, 0,   True, 0, 0, 0, 1, True, 1, "B", 101500}, {0, 0, 0, True, 0,   0, 0, 2, True, 2, "B", 100}, {0, 0, 0, True, 0, 0, 0, 3,   True, 3, "B", 1000}, {0, 0, 0, True, 0, 0, 0, 4, True, 4,   "B", 1000}}

```
Dimensions[myCAans]
```

> > {3000, 12}

Each line of

```
Total[ Select[myCAans , #[[5]] == 0 && #[[10]] == 0 &][[;; , 12]] ]
Total[ Select[myCAans , #[[5]] == 0 && #[[10]] == 1 &][[;; , 12]] ]
Total[ Select[myCAans , #[[5]] == 0 && #[[10]] == 2 &][[;; , 12]] ]
Total[ Select[myCAans , #[[5]] == 1 && #[[10]] == 0 &][[;; , 12]] ]
Total[ Select[myCAans , #[[5]] == 5 && #[[10]] == 6 &][[;; , 12]] ]
```

works fine.

I would like to know how to efficiently find

```
Total[ Select[myCAans , #[[5]] == i && #[[10]] == j &][[;; , 12]] ]
```

for i from 0 to 3 and j from 0 to 3 for example. Something like

```
Total[ Select[myCAans , #[[5]] == i && #[[10]] == j &][[;; , 12]] ] -> XXXXXX  <- Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}]
```

**OP**

On a related question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175312/and-sequence-and), I am struggling to get my head around for this:

```
f@Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}]
f @@ Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}]
f @@@ Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}]
f /@ Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}]

Map[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {2, 2}]

MapAt[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {1}] // TableForm
MapAt[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {2, 1}] // TableForm
MapAt[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {2, 2}] // TableForm
MapAt[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {2, 3}] // TableForm

Map[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {1}] // TableForm
Map[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {2, 1}] // TableForm
Map[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {2, 2}] // TableForm
Map[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {2, 3}] // TableForm
```

Even this

```
MatrixFunction[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}]]
```

The desired output is

```
Table[f[i, j], {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] // TableForm
```

> > {{f[0, 0], f[0, 1], f[0, 2], f[0, 3]}, {f[1, 0], f[1, 1], f[1, 2],   f[1, 3]}, {f[2, 0], f[2, 1], f[2, 2], f[2, 3]}, {f[3, 0], f[3, 1],   f[3, 2], f[3, 3]}}

Final aim is to apply a `pure` function which takes two inputs over an array, like this

[image]

`In163` is one of many trials without a success. I have tested

```
Total[Select[myCAans, (#[[5]] == 0 && #[[10]] == 0) &][[;; , 12]]]
Total[Select[myCAans, (#[[5]] == 0 && #[[10]] == 1) &][[;; , 12]]]
Total[Select[myCAans, (#[[5]] == 0 && #[[10]] == 2) &][[;; , 12]]]
Total[Select[myCAans, (#[[5]] == 0 && #[[10]] == 3) &][[;; , 12]]]




Total[Select[myCAans, (#[[5]] == 3 && #[[10]] == 3) &][[;; , 12]]]
```

which all works perfectly fine.

Any more examples where I can `pick up` mapping pure functions, using `/@` `@@` and `&/@` much easier and faster?

Thanks.

Comment: As I already said in the other post, you can use `Apply` on deeper levels. In this case, you want to have level `{2}`. Try `Apply[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {2}]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Possible to write it using `/@` or `@@` or something similar? Do I have to use the words `Apply` I mean?

Comment: Well, you _could_ use `f @@@ # & /@ array` (where `array = Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}]`, but I would discourage that becaus it is less efficient. And for arrays of rank 3 or higher, you would finally hit the wall with such a syntax.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Didn't seem to be working for my real function `Total[Select[myCAans, (#[[5]] == #1) && (#[[10]] == #2) &][[;; , 12]]]`. I will look for further details.

Comment: Could you show please what `myCAans` is? (A small sample would suffice.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher See updated post. Thanks for your patience and support!

Comment: What about `f = {i, j} \[Function] 
   Total[Select[myCAans, #[[5]] == i && #[[10]] == j &][[;; , 12]]];
Apply[f, Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}], {2}]`? Often, symbols instead of slots (`#`) are a bit better to track...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78907/discussion-between-chen-stats-yu-and-henrik-schumacher).